# How to insert unicode data into varchar2 oracle db column from code or from command line sqlplus command?

Tags: oracle, unicode, varchar2

I am able to insert unicode data (mulitybye etc) into varchar2 oracle db column from Oracle SQL developer and its shown correctly.
But when the same query is put in sql file and run from command prompt using sqlplus command ,then the inserted characters appears garbled.How to resolve this?

Expecting solution from experts . We will need solution without having to modify the datatype of columns to 'NVARCHAR2' or 'NVARCHAR'.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with the: `NLS_CHARACTERSET` settings for your database; the `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements for your sample data; the output of `SELECT column_name, DUMP(column_name) FROM table_name` for your table/column.

Comment: Seems to be an issue with a terminal codepage